# Shortcut to individual items in 'New' menu from context menu in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

I am trying to get a button to create a new, empty zipped folder in the active pane. All I can find is a command to open the context menu mentioned in the title, but no way to access individual options, not even as a parameter.

Is what I am trying to do even possible or is accessing the context menu the best option?

[Context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO2lI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script creates an empty .zip folder.

Copy the following script code to Notepad.
Save the file with a .vbs extension -- e.g., `create_zip_fldr.vbs`

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTimeStamp = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & _
    Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2)
strTimeStamp = strTimeStamp & "-" & Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & _
    Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)
strZipFile = "Compressed (zipped) Folder-" & strTimeStamp & ".zip"
' Create empty ZIP file
fso.CreateTextFile(strZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & _
    String(18, vbNullChar)
```

In Total Commander create a button with the following target:

- Command: C:\windows\system32\wscript.exe
- Parameters: driveletter:\folderpath\create_zip_fldr.vbs

[image]

However, TC doesn't refresh the active pane. To view the newly created zip file, refresh the panel manually. The script can be made to do that (by sending the `F2` key programmatically, but I didn't do that.)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. I assume other items from that context menu can be created in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing but perhaps your problem is that a "new empty zip file" MAKES NO SENSE.

A zip file exists because it has a compressed file or files IN IT.  An empty one isn't a zip file.. I don't think the zip format even supports this.

You can't even add/remove files from a zip.  Technically, adding or removing files from a zip results in creating a new zip and deleting the old one.

Some shells (like explorer and finder) *pretend* that a zip file can be treated as a folder but I assure you that this is smoke and mirrors.

Total commander would have the same issue as explorer and finder.  It has faked something (cool right?) that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I guess you are correct, but I regularly use the context button to make an empty zip, then use F5 to "copy" (zip) files into it. It is true that it says Commpessed (zipped) Folder in the menu. I'll edit the question to reflect that. These smoke and mirrors seem to go a long way.

Comment: Totally :)  I hope you get this solved.